# Javascript function is not executed on the server from c# control on RowDataBound

Tags: javascript, c#, aspxgridview

I am currently calling a javascript function which resides in external file: from C# control in rowdatabound of a grid in .ascx

Javascript Function:

```
function SelectAllAgreements(id, gridID) {
    var grid = document.getElementById(gridID);
    var cell;

    if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i < grid.rows.length; i++) {
            cell = grid.rows[i].cells[0];

            for (j = 0; j < cell.childNodes.length; j++) {
                if (cell.childNodes[j].type == "checkbox") {
                    cell.childNodes[j].checked = document.getElementById(id).checked;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# control code in row databound of the grid:

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelectAll")).Attributes.Add("onclick",
                    "javascript:SelectAllAgreements('" +
                    ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelectAll")).ClientID + "' , '" +
                    ((GridView)this.FindControl("gdvAgreements")).ClientID + "')");
}
```

The code works fine on Localhost but does not work on the server. I am wondering what is happening here. Please assist . Thank you

Comment: I had a similar experience once, and that was because of the data bound in the production site had been broken my HTML tags. Check for any javascript error in the internet browser. And if possible, use the copy of production's data in your localhost as well.

Comment: but if I copy the code on the control it works fine ,it means that the javascript file is not read properly.   The reference of the javascript is on the parent aspx page like this  <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Registrations.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" />
            </Scripts>

Comment: I almost gave up on this issue, it seems so simple yet does not work when referenced external file

Comment: Could you please try it in another browsers? IE, Firefox or Chrome? Is there any signs of javascript errors or something? Have you tried to copy the HTML output of your ASPX page, save it as an HTML page, and then try to open it in the production site (if possible)?